# How to close two Windows by exiting one?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm coding a quizz Application in JavaFX using Mvvm. I have 3 views (one to display all the matches done, an other one to select questions for the quizz and the last one is for the gameQuizz).
The modality of all windows is Application. At the end of the quizz game, I would like to close two Views (GameQuizz and the QuestionSelect) by pressing one button. Does anyone know any solutions ?

Thank you

Comment: add a onCloseRequest handler to both and close the other ..